# What is the javascript exclamation point after variable?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering what the exclamation point after a variable means in javascript?

```
const greet = name => `Hello ${name}!`;
```

Comment: It means the user is really happy to see you. On a more serious note, it's just a plain `!`, it's a normal char.

Comment: With the back-ticks ( slanted single quotation marks ) you can include variables between `${varName}` brackets -- anything that exists outside of them is plain text (string).  So, this line will probably print out something like, "Hello Jason!"

Comment: Disagree, it could mean the user is very surprised :)

Comment: Or it may mean that the app is happy to see the user!